# Find $ \lim\limits_{x \to 0^{+}} x^x $

Tags: calculus, limits

My guess we will have to reformulate the problem in order to be able to use L'Hopital's Rule. Could you give me a hint? Thank you.

Comment: There was no reason to edit this title or to approve the edit. I am going to suggest a rollback because the new edit does not reflect how the original poster intended his post to look.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hint: Try $x^x=e^{\ln x^x}= e^{x \ln x}$.

Comment: Okay and then $$ \lim_{x \to 0^{+}} e^{x \ln x}=e^0=1 $$ Right?

Comment: yes, Ioannis, that is right

Comment: But isn't $\ln x$ undefined? one could also get $e^{- \infty } = 0$

Comment: @DaneBouchie: the thing is, $\lvert \ln x\rvert$ grows slower than $x^{-1/2}$ (in fact, slower than any negative power), so $\lim x \ln x = 0$.

Answer (score 4):

Let $y=x^x$, so $\ln y=x\ln x$ and observe that $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^+}x\ln x=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^+}\frac{\ln x}{1/x}=0$(by L'Hospiatal's rule).

Comment: Alright, thanks!